# ob_flush not working

Tags: php, output-buffering

I searched in all question, I got all answers and suggestions, but none of them helped me.

He's my code:

```
<?php

ini_alter("memory_limit", "1024M");
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('implicit_flush', 'On'); //Inutil já que usa a funcao,, mas vamo testar
error_reporting(0);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_clean();
while (ob_get_level())
    ob_end_flush();

ob_start();
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo $i . '<br>';
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(5);
}
echo ini_get('ob_implicit_flush');
die;
?>
```

And just does not work.
If I use echo ob_get_level() after while, the value is zero.
In php.ini output_buffering value is Off and ob_implicit_flush is On

In my desktop (ubuntu, apache 2.2, php5.3) works fine.
But In my server (centos, httpd 2.2, php5.2), does not work...

Any ideias?

Answer (score 0):

Are your php pages compressed? You can't flush the write buffers if you're compressing on the server with gzip.

Comment: with @apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1); @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0); still does not work

Comment: Unfortunately those headers don't always work in certain hosting environments. Better make sure it isn't zipping your page before moving to the next option.