# php buffer doesn't stop after ob_end_clean

Tags: php, buffering

With the following code I buffer a layout file. 
On local server is works fine, but on the live server it keep buffering until php gives up. This results in a spinning progressbar and a delayed executing of al the javascript in the page. It looks like ob_end_clean() doensn't really quit the buffering.

```
ob_start();
require($layoutfile);
$return = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $return;
```

When I echo a space after flushing the buffers stops and every thing works normal. But in this context I won't print anything to the screen.

```
ob_start();
require($layoutfile);
$return = ob_get_contents();
if(ob_end_clean()) echo " ";
return $return;
```

anybody ran into this?

Comment: have you tried using `ob_flush`?

Comment: @kuba with 'ob_flush' it deletes the '$return' var

Comment: Curious. As a test, does replacing `ob_end_clean();` with `if (ob_get_level()) while (@ob_end_clean());` allow the script to work correctly?

Comment: @webbiedave nope that doesn't work. Could it have something to do with the server conf? On other servers & local, it work fine!

Comment: I'm not sure. Only things that come to mind are checking for any bugs with the PHP version on the server, trying to turn on/off compression in the web server, checking the Apache [SendBufferSize](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#sendbuffersize).

Comment: If it works on other servers, it may be the gzip cfg setting. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908299/ob-flush-not-working

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone having buffer issues:**

Try `echo ob_get_level()` to see in which layer you are.  If this function returns more than `0` you are still inside a buffer.

To close all layers an prevent problems, do the following:

```
while (@ob_end_clean()) {  
    // do nothing   
}
```

This will delete all layers.

After this you can move go on - even with only `flush()` instead of `ob_flush()`.

You mentioned it works on your other server. Do you have gzip compression activated like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908299/ob-flush-not-working)?

Answer (score 0):

The code that works fine for me is:

```
<?php

include "../connect/connectdb.php";

$txtIdCaso = $_GET['WWW_id_caso'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM caso_solicitud
        WHERE id_caso = '".$txtIdCaso."'";


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row    = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: "'.$row['tipo_archivo'].'"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$row['nombre_archivo'].'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'); 
header('Pragma: public');
header("Content-length: ".$row['longitud_archivo']);

while (@ob_end_clean()) {  
// do nothing   
}

die($row['doc_solicitud']);
?>
```

Hope that can help. I tested several types of formats and works fine.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is output after the `ob_end_clean`. Using `die`/`exit`/`header` will work fine (Means there will be nothing in the HTML). I just ran into similar problem but got the solution.
Output buffering deals with output to client side and the function cleans everything till it is executed.